# R copy text from function output with for loop to clipboard

Tags: r, function, for-loop, clipboard

I've written a little function that helps renaming columns by looping through each variable and pasting various punctuation around it so that text is sent to the console. This can then be copied into my script and rename variables as required. This is the function:

```
library(tidyverse)
tidy_rename <- function (df) {
  df_name <- deparse(substitute(df))
  names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
  cat(paste(df_name, " <- ", paste(df_name, "%>%\n\t rename(")))
  for (i in names(df)) {
    cat(paste("\t\t", paste(paste("=", paste(paste('"', i), '"'))), ","), sep="\n")
  }
  writeLines(")"
  )
}
```

If I use this on a dataset:

```
test_df <- data.frame("VarIable 1" = c(1), "sizrd" = c(1), "dat 1" = c(1), 
                      "x-cord" = c(1), "y-crf" = c(1), "aGe" = c(1), check.names=F)
tidy_rename(test_df)
```

which gives the following which can be copied and pasted into script:

```
test_df  <-  test_df %>%
     rename(         = " variable 1 " ,
         = " sizrd " ,
         = " dat 1 " ,
         = " x-cord " ,
         = " y-crf " ,
         = " age " ,
)
```

What I would like is to automatically copy this output to the clipboard within the function. I'm not sure how to use `writeClipboard` around the `forloop`. This doesn't work:

```
tidy_rename <- function (df) {
  df_name <- deparse(substitute(df))
  names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
  writeClipboard(
  cat(paste(df_name, " <- ", paste(df_name, "%>%\n\t rename(")))
  for (i in names(df)) {
    cat(paste("\t\t", paste(paste("=", paste(paste('"', i), '"'))), ","), sep="\n")
  }
  writeLines(")"
  )
  )
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Suggestion: Create a variable and concatenate the result `str <- paste(str, newstr, sep = "\n")` after the `loop` call `writeClipboard(str)`.

Comment: thanks, do you mean `str <- (cat(paste(df_name......writeLines(")"
  )`? I can't seem to work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment to eliminate any confusion.

A method or suggestion is to store the string in a variable, which can then be output in the end. Note from the **`value`** of `cat(...)` is NULL (it doesnt return the string). This requires 2 variables, lets call them `str` and `newstr`. I'll let `str` store the entire string that you want to copy, and `newstr` store the current string that is output by `cat(...)`.

```
tidy_rename <- function (df) {
    df_name <- deparse(substitute(df))
    names(df) <- tolower(names(df))

    str <- paste(df_name, " <- ", paste(df_name, "%>%\n\t rename(")) 
    cat(str)
    for (i in names(df)) {
        #Store variable at each iteration and expand str. Output newstr.
        newstr <- paste("\t\t", paste(paste("=", paste(paste('"', i), '"'))), ",")
        str <- paste(str, newstr, sep = "\n")
        cat(newstr, sep="\n")
    }
    newstr <- ")"
    str <- paste0(str, newstr)
    cat(newstr)
    writeClipboard(str)
}
```

Note how the output is stored in `str` at each iteration but `newstr` is output.

As a side note i suggest that OP checks out the `collapse` argument of `paste` (alternatively `paste0`). I don't have the full overview, but it seems like this could eliminate 2 - 3 calls to `paste` if the strings were collapsed within one of the function calls.

Comment: No problem. Note that i am mean the `collapse ` argument in either `paste` or `paste0`. It can be used to concatenate vectors `paste0(c("I", "am", "a", "cat"), collapse = " ")` for example. For simplicity `paste0(...)` is equivalent (but every slightly faster than) `paste(..., sep = "")`. :-)